# Подключена ли библиотека?

Tags: java

Как определить,была ли подключена библиотека математических функций?

Comment: Вызвать какую-нибудь из них?

Comment: День добрый. Вопрос конкретизируйте. Вы хотите понять, есть ли нужная библиотека/класс в итоговой сборке?

Comment: Да,именно это. Понимаю,что можно посмотреть в сам код,но как ещё можно понять,что нужная библиотека подключена в сборке.